# SignalR client issues "Failed to complete negotiation with the server: TypeError: fetch failed" error message in a node application

Tags: node.js, signalr, signalr-hub, ts-jest, azure-signalr

We have an Azure Function App running on our development machine (http://locahost:7071/api) with `negotiate` endpoint pointing to an Azure Serverless signalR instance. The function app has the following configuration:

```json
    "Host": {
        "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
        "CORS": "*"
    }
```

The typescript application's implementation to negotiate looks in a `Promise<boolean>` function like the following code snippet:

```js
const options: IHttpConnectionOptions = {
                accessTokenFactory: () => '',
                logger: this.logger,
                logMessageContent: true,
                headers: { 
                    'x-ms-signalr-userid' : 'myuserid',
                    'x-functions-key' : 'myfunckey'
                }
            }; 
this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
          .withUrl(`http://localhost:7071/api`, options)
          .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
          .withAutomaticReconnect()
          .build();

this.hubConnection.start().then(() => {
     this.logger?.log(LogLevel.Information, "Hub connection established.");
     resolve(true);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.logger?.log(LogLevel.Critical, `Unable to establish a connection to the hub. The start failed: ${error}`);
        reject(false);
   });
```

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^7.0.5",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.5"
  }
```

Unfortunately this code running in **Jest** never "negotiates" successfully due to the following error message:

> Failed to complete negotiation with the server: TypeError: fetch failed

**Additional notes:** The breakpoint never hits the Azure Function Function's `negotiate` endpoint (in C#) when running the function app in debug mode.

As a side note, we also have a test .NET application that negotiates flawlessly whose negotiation routine is similar to the share code's implementation.

How to address this issue in this code snippet to make the negotiation work?

Answer (score 0):

Jest is not a browser environment and as such doesn't have `fetch` defined. Ideally, unit tests shouldn't be making actual calls and instead should mock requests.

But nonetheless, it isn't impossible to do. Importing [`isomorphic-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch) at the top of file where you have your tests should do the trick I believe.